# Removing items from a list where the Id is in another list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I see this questions is quite common yet none of the answers work as expected.  I have a list of objects and I need to remove some of those objects when their Id is in a specified list.  I tried List.RemoveAll but that just returns an integer, not the modified list.  How do I get back my list, minus the removed items?

```
List<Target> allServers = GetTargets(Group.Id);
List<long> excludedServers = GetExcludedServers();

List<Target> patchServers = allServers
    .RemoveAll(x => !excludedServers.Any(y => y.Id == x.Id));
```

Comment: RemoveAll modifies your existing List, it returns the number of items it removed.

Comment: if _excludedServers_ is a list of long, how do you manage to compile y.Id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[RemoveAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) modifies your existing List, it returns the number of items it removed. To get a new list without the items you can use

```
var newList = myList.Where(i => !excludedItems.Any(ei => ei.Id == i.Id)).ToList();
```

Although if your `Server` class has the right equality members to compare Ids, you could just write

```
var newList = myList.Except(servers).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
List<Target> allServers = GetTargets(Group.Id);
List<long> excludedServers = GetExcludedServers();

List<Target> patchServers = allServers
    .Where(x => !excludedServers.Any(y => y.Id == x.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
patchServers = allServers.Where(x => !excludedServers.Contains(x.id)).ToList();
```